# Calling multiple functions with similar names

Tags: c++

If I have multiple functions that have a similar name (ie fct1, fct2, fct3...), and I'm calling them from a menu that takes the function number in parameter, is there a way to call them without making a switch with every function?

I'm thinking of something similar to this: `fct[c](); //c is entered by the user`, which of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert them all to map... key is the std::string which is the function name
value is a function pointer.

Once you initialize the map you can use map look up to find and execute the function and avoid a switch statement

```
typedef void (*Foo)(void);

std::map< std::string , Foo> FunctionMap;
//Change key type to int if numbers are needed

void PrintA()
{
    std::cout << "PrintA" << std::endl;
}

void PrintB()
{
    std::cout << "PrintA" << std::endl;
}

void ExecuteFunction( const std::string& funcName )
{
    std::map< std::string , Foo>::const_iterator iter = FunctionMap.find(funcName);
    if ( iter != FunctionMap.end() )
    {
        Foo f = iter->second;
        f();
    }
}

int main()
{

    FunctionMap["PrintA"] = PrintA;
    FunctionMap["PrintB"] = PrintB;

    ExecuteFunction("PrintA");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you could just use a `std::vector` and index them the way you described in your question.  This would be a better solution if you have lots of functions you could call.

Comment: On the other hand, the `map` approach is amenable to simplification using a preprocessor macro a la `#define MAPFUNCTION(map, name) map[#name] = name`...

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-declare a list of function pointers.  Thusly:

```
void Func1() { std::cout << "Func1" << std::endl; }
void Func2() { std::cout << "Func2" << std::endl; }
void Func3() { std::cout << "Func3" << std::endl; }

void (*funcList[])() = {Func1, Func2, Func3};

int main()
{
    funcList[0]();
    funcList[1]();
    funcList[2]();  
}
```

```
Func1
Func2
Func3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Edit: an example of initializing the array at runtime - it's like any other array of values, it just looks funny when declared.

```
void (*funcList[3])() = {};

void InitFuncList()
{
    funcList[0] = Func1;
    funcList[1] = Func2;
    funcList[2] = Func3;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this, but I am not sure how to do it with a header file. The functions are declared in my header file, and defined in a function.cpp file. The void `(*funcList[])() = {Func1, Func2, Func3{;` goes where?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the functions are declared in a header file - you declare the function pointer list wherever you'll be using it.  In my example it was declared as a global and statically allocated.

You could also initialize it at runtime, which I'll edit into the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option in standard C++ is to populate some kind of lookup from keys to function pointers. That could be a map using the strings as keys, or an array using the number as an index, or for that matter the switch you mentioned or a big old `if/else` statement comparing string values.

If you're willing to write non-portable code, look at the facilities that your system provides for looking up functions by name in an executable (`dlsym`, `GetProcAddress` or equivalent). As long as your functions are available in a symbol table, you can get at them that way. The question becomes almost equivalent to [Is it possible to call a C function, given its name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184613/is-it-possible-to-call-a-c-function-given-its-name-as-a-string), except that you also have C++ name mangling to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If the functions all have the same signature, you can put function pointers into an array.  For instance,

```
int option1 ()
{
}

int option2 ()
{
}

typedef int(*option)();

const option options[] = {
    &option1,
    &option2,
};
int n = sizeof(options) / sizeof(option);

int main ( int, char ** )
{
    for ( int choice = 0; (std::cin >> choice); )
    {
        if ((choice < 0) || (choice >= n)) {
            std::cout << "Invalid option." << std::endl;
        } else {
            (*options[choice])();
        }
    }
}
```