# How can I cast an char array to a function pointer in C?

Tags: c, linux, string, casting, function-pointers

Is it possible to assign with cast to a function pointer a string or char array and then run it?

I have defined a few functions `int f1();`, `int f2();`, and so on

In the `main()` function I have read a string `fct_name` and declared a pointer to function `int (*pv)();`

I need to do something like this:

the `fct_name` can have values "f1" , "f2" and so on..

```
pv = (some sort of cast)fct_name;

pv();
```

My point is I want to avoid conditional instructions in favor of direct assignment (because I have a large number of functions in my program)

The code must obviously run.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, why?

Comment: "The code must obviously run" is the difficult part here. It might not because of no execute bits, etc. Have fun reading shell code tutorials.

Comment: Oh, your question edit has just completely changed the apparent meaning of your question...

Comment: Why don't you step back and tell us about your problem rather than your imagined solution. Then we might be able to help.

Comment: I have a large number of functions and each one is related to a command which the user must type as input. I want to avoid something like 20 if statements to check which function to call. I thought it is possible to do that with function pointers in C

Comment: @user37468: user input is _much_ slower than 20 _if_ statements.

Comment: @ninjalj: but most things are more flexible/clean than 20 if statements.

Comment: You can easily create a static table of (constant string, function pointer) pairs and use that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call a function named in a string variable in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118705/call-a-function-named-in-a-string-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have an external library and are trying to call functions declared in your executable, you can do a lookup yourself

```
#define REGISTER_FUNC(name)  {#name, name}

struct funclist
{
    const char* name;
    void (*fp)(void);  //or some other signature
};

struct funclist AllFuncs[] = {
    REGISTER_FUNC(f1),
    REGISTER_FUNC(f2),
    REGISTER_FUNC(f3),
    {NULL,NULL}  //LAST ITEM SENTINEL
 };
```

Now you can lookup your variable `fct_name` in `AllFuncs`.  You can use a linear search if the number is small, or insert them all into a hash table for O(1) lookup.

Alternately, if your names really are `f1`, `f2`, etc. you can just do

```
   void (*FuncList)(void)[]  = {NULL, f1,f2,f3};
   ...
   int idx = atol(fct_name+1);
   if (idx && idx < MAX_FUNCS)  
       FuncList[idx]();
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant of Carey's answer, in case you're on a *nix system. `dlopen()` opens up your library. `RTLD_LAZY` tells the loader to not bother resolving all the library's symbols right away, and to wait for you to try to access them. `dlsym()` looks up the symbol in question.

**Edit:** Updated the snippet to better fit your clarification:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *handle = dlopen("libexample.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        // error
    }

    char fct_name[64];

    // read input from terminal here

    void *func = dlsym(handle, fct_name);

    if (func != NULL) {
        // call function here; need to cast as appropriate type
    }
}
```

libexample.so would be a library with your functions, compiled as a shared library, like so:

```
gcc -Wall -o libexample.so example.c -shared -fPIC
```

That being said, if you're going to the trouble of compiling a shared library like this, you'll probably just want to call the functions in your binary. You can do that if you link your library in at compile-time:

```
gcc -Wall -o test test.c -L. -lexample
```

`-L.` tells the linker to look for libraries in the current directory (`.`) and `-lexample` tells it to link with a library named "libexample.so". If you do this, you can just call the library functions directly within your program.

Comment: Note also -- if you link with `-rdynamic`, you can use `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, name)` to find a function in your executable, without ever calling dlopen...

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a char array to a function just because the array happens to contain the name of a function.  What you need to do is put your function(s) in a DLL and then do this:

```
HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("foo.dll");
pv func = (pv)GetProcAddress(module, fct_name);
```

Comment: Sorry, it had no Linux tag when I saw it.  Concept still applies.  See Dan's answer.