# UIKit additions: bridging the gap between eg CGRectValue and NSStringFromCGRect?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to implement a specialized `typed` logger that takes a dictionary as input and creates string of values out of it.

One sample such dictionary might be:

```
CGSize size = {300, 200} ;
CGAffineTransform t = ::CGAffineTransformIdentity ;

[self logit: @{
    @"columns": @{
        @"value": @3
    ,   @"type": @"NSNumber"
    }
,   @"size": @{
        @"value": [NSValue valueWithCGSize(size)]
    ,   @"type": @"CGSize"
    }
,   @"transform": @{
        @"value": [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform(t)]
    ,   @"type":    @"CGAffineTransform"
    }
}] ;
```

The issue is: how do I retrieve those values in a generic way?

I could obviously write

```
    for (NSString * key in dict) {
        NSDictionary * params = dict[key] ;

        if ([params[@"type"] isEqualToString: @"CGRect"]) {
            CGRect r = [params[@"value"] CGRectValue] ;
            NSString * s = ::NSStringFromCGRect(r) ;
            ::NSLog(s) ;
        } else if ([params[@"type"] isEqualToString: @"NSNumber"]) {
            ::NSLog(@"%.3f", [params[@"value"] floatValue]) ;
        } else if ([params[@"type"] isEqualToString: @"CGAffineTransform"]) {
            CGAffineTransform t = [params[@"value"] CGAffineTransformValue]
            NSString * s = ::NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(t) ;
            ::NSLog(s) ;
        }
        ...
    }
```

But I'd rather write a more "generic" solution. Something along the lines:

```
SEL valueSelector = ::NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Value", params[@"type"]) ;
NSString * rawCFunctionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NSStringFrom%@", params[@"type"]] ;
```

So now I have a selector and the name of a C function.

1. How do I go from a string to a C function that I can actually call?
2. using the selector above is unclear as its return type can vary from `id` e.g.: in the case of `NSNumber *` to "plain C object" e.g. in the case of `CGRect`, `CGSize` etc ...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't; see "[Call a function named in a string variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118705/call-a-function-named-in-a-string-variable-in-c)".
2. Yup, you have to know the return type at compile time.

All is not lost, however: what you're trying to do can actually be accomplished in a fairly mundane way. `NSValue` has the very nice feature that its `description` method gives output very similar to the appropriate `NSStringFrom...()` function for the type it's storing (it's probably using them under the hood). For example:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMake(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(10, 10)]);
```

yields:

> 2013-08-11 03:06:43.053 PrintingNSValue[51538:11303] CGAffineTransform: {{10, 10, 10, 10}, {10, 10}}
>   2013-08-11 03:06:43.055 PrintingNSValue[51538:11303] NSSize: {10, 10}

`NSNumber` will likewise give a nice representation of its value as its description.

So all you have to do is something like this:

```
for( NSString * key in theDictionary ){
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", key, theDictionary[key][@"value"]);
}
```